# Marginal Homogeneity and (SPARSE) Ordered Categories

Tags: heteroscedasticity, ordinal-data, likert, marginal-distribution, sparse

I'm trying to compare pre-test responses on a 5-Point Likert item to post-test responses on (the same) 5-Point Likert Item.

The responses I observed as shown in the following table:

\begin{array} {|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&1 &2 &  3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
1& 0 &1  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2& 0 &0  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3& 0 &0  & 0 & 7 & 2 \\
4& 0 &0  & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
5& 0 &0  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}

The test for marginal homogeneity and ordered categories (Agresti 2007, p. 254) should let me make this paired comparison. Notably, however, there were a lot of cells with zero values among my responses. Due to all these zeros, I get the estimated statistic $\hat{\beta} = \infty$. That said, what can I do to still perform this test? Is there some reasonable way to cope with all these extra zeros?

Comment: I tried collapsing the levels of the items. This reduces the table to a 2x2 contingency table. However, the half of the matrix below the diagonal still contains only zeros.

Comment: Is it unreasonable to collapse the levels to yield a 2x2 contingency table and then impute the zero values by a small amount (say 0.5)? Is this test still valid?